# Symfony can not find config_.yml

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have a symfony project of which I can't clear the cache of all of a sudden. I only made some changes to twig. I always clean the cache with the following command.

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e
```

After executing the command I get the following message:

> The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\postcodezoeker\app/config/config_.yml" does not exist.

After searching on Google I found some other post on Stackoverflow. They pointed out to use the following command which executes with no errors.

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

[image]

But when I go to webpage I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser in C:\xampp\htdocs\postcodezoeker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser.php on line 24

I created a clean new project and tried to execute the commands and still got the same thing. Reinstalling XAMPP did not do the trick and a newer version of symfony neither.

I hope you guys can help me out. I use PHP version 5.6.15 and Symfony 3.4

Comment: Which version of 3.4 are you using? An issue for your second error has been solved: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25334

Comment: @DFayet Version 3.4.0

Comment: As mentionned in the linked issue, try to update to, at least, 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call you are using does not provide any information about the environment:

`php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e`

...forces Symfony to run using the environment   (empty string). The service configuration is read from the file `config_.yml` afterwards, which (according to that error message) does not exist.

Either provide a value for the environment (for example using `-e prod`) or don't use `-e` after all.